# How to create textbox dynamically?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I just want to create a **textbox**, which appears only if certain conditions are met!
What i want is that, if the conditions are met the **textbox** should appear.

If the conditions are not met, then it should not be visible (not just changing the visibility of the textbox to collapsed),i.e there should not be an empty place too.

How can i do this??

Comment: You are going to need to post some of your code to provide some context for us. This sounds like a simple visibility binding.

Answer (score 1):

XAML provides rich **data binding** mechanism for MVVM pattern. You have to:

1. Implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` in `ViewModel`
2. Create a property with `PropertyChanged` event of `INotifyPropertyChanged` fired in setter in `ViewModel` with data type of `TextBox` visibility
3. In XAML, [bind this property](http://www.wintellect.com/blogs/jlikness/model-view-viewmodel-mvvm-explained) to your `TextBox`

Then, changing this property somewhere automatically leads to changing `TextBox` state

Answer (score 1):

Add a textbox inside the grid object like

```
    Grid grid=new Grid(){Height=60,Width=100};
    Textbox tBox=new Textbox(){Text="Sample",Visibility=Visibility.Collapsed};
    grid.Children.Add(tBox);
```

now conditions

```
if(Condition==true)
{
tBox.Visibility=Visibility.Visible;
}
else
{
tBox.Visibility=Visibility.Collapsed;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think there is no need to create TextBox dynamically. you should manage it by creating TextBox in xaml and TextBox Visibility. When you create our TextBox in xaml remember that Height should be default of TextBox. 
Here is the sample

```
<TextBox x:Name="txtVisible" Visibility="Collapsed"/>

 if(Condition==met)
   txtVisible.Visibility=Visibility.Visible;
 else
  txtVisible.Visibility=Visibility.Collapsed;
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use panels I think. Put something under to panel, put panel and then put textbox on it. And make panel invisible by default. If conditions are met u can make panel visible by code